# Set the body element to always occupy 100% of the width and height of the visual viewport on iPhone

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

How do I set the body element to always occupy 100% of the width and height of the visual viewport on the iPhone?  I want to center elements vertically and horizontally within the visual viewport (UIWebView).

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
<img src="#" style="margin:0 auto;" />
```

Comment: No it won't work because the body element extends beyond the visual viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```